# Reverse back the and operator

Tags: image, image-processing, cryptography, pixel, steganography

Please how can I get second operand of **AND** operator if the one value and the result was given.

In multiplication, we divide to get the second value, in addition we subtract to get the second value.

Please, how can we get the second value in *logical* operator

[image]

I have this calculation

(16114095 AND F8F8FC) OR 394752

Which result to be this **16180908**

And I want to retrieve **394752** from the give parameter (result) 16180908 and F8F8FC to get **394752**

I have used both the left bitwise and write bitwise

Comment: You can't do it, the bitwise AND operator is **not** invertible.

Comment: Consider the most basic case of one bit. If I tell you the output is 0, what are the inputs? If you cannot solve this for one bit (and it cannot be solved for one bit), you cannot solve it for more.

Comment: that's why everyone uses `xor` or addition for this. `and`/`or` are equivalent to `min`/`max`.